# Is there a way to open an appliction from Internet Browser?

Tags: software-center, browser, url

I just wonder when I visit [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/) that when I click the banner *Available On The Software Center* , It Opens the application *Software Center*.

I just want to know what is the *URL* for a specific application to it to be opened with Internet Browser ?

So does an application in Ubuntu has a *IP* address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An URL consists of not only an **address**, but also of a **protocol**. The latter is what the apps directory uses to open the Software Center.

The link on the Gnome Schedule page points to `apt://gnome-schedule`. Your browser has been instructed to redirect `apt://` links to the Software Center. In technical terms, the Software Center has been registered as a **protocol handler** for the `apt://` protocol.

This only works because both the website and your system know about the protocol.